# Python how to call either of the two columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have big data frame of many columns. I want to either of the two columns at any time.

```
df.columns = ['c1','c1T1','c2','c2T1',...........,'c10','c10T1',
'c30','c30T2','c40','c40T2',...........,'c60','c60T2']
```

I know that the column names are `'c1',...,'c4'`. There is another column associated with each of these. 
My logic of calling the second column is `'c1'+['T1' or 'T2']`. I know that there is only one column `'c1T1'`, not `'c1T2'`. so, how to search such combination in `df[]`.

My present code:

```
   df[['c1','c1'+'T1'|.'T2']]
```

My present output:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to call the second column associated with the first?

Comment: Less verbose comment: I'd recommend watching some introductory python tutorials first to grasp the syntax right, that'll help you not get stuck in syntax errors. Here, I'd suggest you to try to use `df.filter(like='c1')` to find columns with `c1` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automate the creation of columns names that you want using lists & then use that list to look to the columns you need. Code below.

You can change the lists `prefixes` & `postfixes` to get the columns you need.

```
prefixes = ['c1']
postfixes = ['', 'T1','T2']
colsToCheck = [prefix+postfix for prefix in prefixes for postfix in postfixes]
cols = [col for col in colsToCheck if col in df.columns]  
df[cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

the following gives a syntax error ['c1','c1'+'T1'|.'T2'] because of the "." but even without that you can't use | with strings. The way I would resolve this issue would be to generate the list of column names you would potentially want to check (in this case ['c1','c1T1','c1T2']) and use a list comprehension to grab the elements that are in df.columns.

```
cols_to_check = ['c1','c1T1','c1T2']  
select_cols = [col for col in cols_to_check if col in df.columns]  
df[select_cols]
```